# How to custom format date with javascirpt and jquery

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set the date with a formatted date but I don't know how to do that can you please help me to do it. the default i get is **"17/11/201"** but i want **"Nov 17, 20021"** and how to disable past dates with this code thank you so much for helping me

```
const input = document.createElement('input');

input.type = "date"
input.id = "scheduleTime"
input.className = "input-text";
input.value = new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleDateString('en-CA');
```

Answer (score 0):

new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'short', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric' })

More info is here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Regards to past dates try to use the min attribute.
Examples are here.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp

Comment: I try your code but not working and I see the reference also the same but still not working and it's not set the current date after paste your code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi @HengSeyha
I have updated the answer.
Please try this

new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'short', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric' })

Answer (score 0):

If it was me i would use the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library

It allows you to do the following:

```
moment().format('MMM DD, YYYY')
```

As apposed to the native solution, which would be something along the lines of:

```
new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString('en-CA', { month: 'short', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric' });
```

Comment: how to import moment js in chrome extention

Comment: It is not a chrome extension, you will need to include this in your project. There are a number of ways to add this. If you simply want to add it via a script tag you can use the following:
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>`

Or you can follow the guide via https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/